# Autosave files in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any setting to 'auto save files before running in VS Code'?
Acually I always have to save files before running with the "Code Runner" extension of VS Code. Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

In the **File** tab of the application you can find a button that says **Auto Save**, toggle it. See [this](https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-toggle-auto-save-in-vs-code/) for a visual guide.